# How to redirect https://www to https:// and http://www to https:// and http:// to https://

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all the following addresses :

- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`

to `https://example.com` using a permanent redirect in an .htaccess file.

Comment: There are several answers for this on SO. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

# URL with www rewrite to https without www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%2%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# URL without www rewrite to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You don't have a capturing group (to match `$1`) in the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (or, change the backreference to `$0`). But neither will this redirect `http://example.com`.

Comment: You are right, missed that part. I've edited my post. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Minor tidy... the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ...` directive in the second ruleset would seem to be superfluous given the rule above. No need to parenthesis _all_ the sub patterns unless they need to be captured. (You can't actually capture groups in a negated regex anyway.)